# BERTopic Visualization in dark

Tags: python, nlp, plotly, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I want to change the default visualizations within BERTopic to display a dark theme rather than a white or bright theme.

Basically I'm trying to do:

```
   import plotly.io as pio
   pio.templates.default = 'plotly_dark'
   
   topic_model.visualize_barchart(top_n_topics=44, n_words=10)
   topic_model.visualize_topics()
   topic_model.visualize_distribution(topic_distr[doc_id], min_probability=0.05)
```

I'm expecting this way the dark theme would be used to instead it remains using the white default theme. Any ideas as to how i can change that behavior?

Comment: The template used in BERTopic visualization is hard-coded, you can try to override it by modifying the plotly figure object returned by those functions, ie. `fig = topic_model.visualize_barchart(...)` then `fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark')`.

Comment: Thank you @EricLavault this worked perfectly.